# libGdx array<TextureRegion> fails to assign to Sprite

Tags: java, libgdx

After a long search on StackOverflow and Google I decided to write a question myself as I did not find a solution for my problem. I am learning libgdx from a 'learning LibGdx game development' book. I confirmed that my code is exactly the same as the code provided in the book. Everything runs fine until it reaches this part:

```
Sprite spr = new Sprite(regions.random());
```

`Region.randoms()` is an `Array<TextureRegion>`. It works fine if I add direct instance of an asset from a `Asset` class but crashes if I want to add a random asset from `Array<TextureRegion>`. Why?

```
private void initTestObj () {
    // creates new array for 5 sprite's 
    testSprites = new Sprite[5];

    // Create a list of texture regions
    Array<TextureRegion> regions = new Array<TextureRegion>();
    regions.add(Assets.instance.bunny.head);
    regions.add(Assets.instance.ballon.ballon);
    regions.add(Assets.instance.spider.spider);

    System.out.println("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx test before Sprite xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    System.out.println(regions.size);

    //create new sprite's using a random texture region
    for( int i = 0; i < testSprites.length ; i++) {
        Sprite spr = new Sprite(regions.random()); //<<<< Main problem

        System.out.println(".....................test after sprite...............");

        //define sprite size to be 1x1 in game world
        spr.setSize(1 , 1);

        //set origin to sprite's center
        spr.setOrigin(spr.getWidth() / 2.0f, spr.getHeight() / 2.0f);

        //calculate random position for sprite
        float randomX = MathUtils.random(-2.0f, 2.0f);
        float randomY = MathUtils.random(-2.0f, 2.0f);
        spr.setPosition(randomX, randomY);

        // put new sprite into array
        testSprites[i] = spr;   
    }
    //set first sprite as selected one 
    selectedSprite = 0;
```

Comment: Are you sure that your texture regions are not null ?

Comment: Hey Paul, thanks for a response. It seems that you are on to something when I run  'Sprite spr = new Sprite(regions.get(0));' at zero location asset exists and it displays on the screen, but it seems that it does'nt add other Assets to an array<TextureRegion>. When I run 'System.out.println(regions.get(2)); & System.out.println(regions.get(1));' it returns null , but if I run Array.size it Returns 3 does that not mean that there are 3 instances in the array?

Comment: Thanks for pointing at the right direction. I got it working eventually there was nothing wrong with texture region array there was problem with assets,  apparently you cant name them like item_1 because after packing texture packer discards the _1 a the end and you left with just item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working eventually there was nothing wrong with texture region array there was problem with assets, apparently you cant name them like item_1 because after packing texture packer discards the _1 a the end and you left with just item.